# How to create new CallBack With retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit in my application to download some JSONs from he server. But some times when i request duplicated data from server it returns response code 208 with null body, But in 200 i have a response body that is not null.
In null bodies retrofit goes to onFailure method. My problem is here!
I want to know the reason of failed request(it's because 208(in my case) or other things). How can i get response code in OnFailure method?

I Tried to implement my own callBack method like this:

```
public class DefaultCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

  private static final String TAG = "LOGO_SendReport";
  private Callback<T> callback;

  public DefaultCallback(Callback<T> callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
  }

  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
    if (response.body() == null) {

      callback.onFailure(call, new NullPointerException("Empty response"));
      Log.e(TAG, "Response code is: " + response.code());

    } else {
      callback.onResponse(call, response);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
    Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
    callback.onFailure(call, t);
  }
}
```

This is my Call:

```
 @POST("office/report")
  Call<ResponseSendReport> sendReport(@Body SendReport pendingList);
```

This is my final method:

```
    final APIService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(APIService.class, App.Auth);

            Call<ResponseSendReport> call = service.sendReport(sendReport);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseSendReport>() {
              @Override
              public void onResponse(Call<ResponseSendReport> call, Response<ResponseSendReport> response) {

                Log.i("LOGO_SendReport", "code is:  " + response.code());


                if (response.code() == 200) {


              }

              @Override
              public void onFailure(Call<ResponseSendReport> call, Throwable t) {

                /*When Response code is 208 Goes here and I want to get 
                 response code 
                 if it is 208 to handle it! */
              }
            });
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can create abstract class and handle cases.

```
public abstract class DefaultCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

   @SuppressWarnings({"ConstantConditions", "unchecked"})
   @Override public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
       if (response.isSuccessful()) {
           onSuccess(response.body(), response.code());
       } else {
           onError(response.errorBody(), response.code());
       }
   }

   @Override public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<T> call, @NonNull Throwable throwable) {
       onError(null, -1);
   }

   public abstract void onSuccess(@NonNull final T response, int code);

   public abstract void onError(@Nullable ResponseBody body, int code);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the response code inside `onResponse` method using `response.code()`

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseSendReport> call, Response<ResponseSendReport> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        if (response.code() == 208) {
           //do sth
        } else {
           //do sth
        }
    } else {
        //do sth
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You can simply modify your call:

```
 @POST("office/report")
 Call<Response<ResponseSendReport>> sendReport(@Body SendReport pendingList);
```

2.This is Your final method:

```
 @Override
 public void onFailure(Call<Response<ResponseSendReport>> response, Throwable t) {

    response.code() //  /** HTTP status code. */
    response.body() //your object
          }
        });
```